# Twitter embedded timeline by username

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, integration

I'm trying to programmatically construct an embedded Twitter timeline from an arbitrary username. I feel like this should be possible if the user's Tweets are public, but I'm not sure since I haven't found anything specific that does this. I would really like to avoid third-party libraries and use services provided only by Twitter if possible.

I was referring to this documentation: https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines

I found this HTML example on the page I linked that can be used to embed a Twitter feed but if I simply change the username, it breaks:

```html
<a class="twitter-timeline"
  data-widget-id="600720083413962752"
  href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev"
  width="300"
  height="300">
Tweets by @TwitterDev
</a>
```

I see a way to construct an embedded timeline for your personal Twitter account, but no way to do this for an arbitrary Twitter user whose Tweets are public. Anyone recently try something like this or have any suggestions?

Comment: Don't copy paste that code, you have to create a personal widget. Read that page further please ;)  Click: https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new

Answer (score 0):

Veeery short answer: https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the response! But this doesn't directly answer my question. I was looking for a way to dynamically generate the timeline widget using only a Twitter username.